# why does this post implementation return 404 in node/express?

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

The following URL provides a pretty good walkthrough of how to wire up a node/express implementation to read from Google Cloud Platform Cloud SQL:

https://medium.com/@austinhale/building-a-node-api-with-express-and-google-cloud-sql-9bda260b040f

I implemented the steps in this article and my local implementation is working as expected.  However, this URL doesn't cover how to wire up inserts/updates.  Based on some googling, I came up with the following implementation for a post/insert:

```
// POST method route
app.post('/users', function (req, res) {
  var post = { FirstName: req.FirstName, LastName: req.LastName };
  var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO User SET ?', post, function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error){
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  });
})
```

I'm POST-ing the following request from Postman as raw JSON:

```
http://localhost:3000/users/
{
    "FirstName":"John",
    "LastName":"Smith"
}
```

However, the response status is 404 Not Found.  The standard GET is working as expected though.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong here?  Also, I'm new to Node/Express.  What's the easiest way to get started debugging?  For example, is there a recommended plugin for CDT that I can use for this?  The sample code that I used for the GET used console.log("message") but when I tried this approach, nothing appeared to be written out to the node console window or to CDT?

Comment: Note:  Your `app.post()` does not send any response.  It needs to `res.send()` something.  Also, `req.FirstName` should be `req.body.FirstName` - same for `LastName`.  And, you will have to make sure you have the appropriate JSON parsing middleware to populate `req.body` as shown [here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html).

Comment: I'm still getting the 404 behavior.  Here's the full source:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git-it-2020/random/master/express-post-404

Comment: I even tried the most basic POST implementation, where I simply res.send() a basic message but a Postman POST still returns 404:

// POST method route
app.post('/users', function (req, res) {
res.send('POST request to insert supplier');
})

Comment: If you insert a `console.log("got /users")` into the route, does it get logged? If not, the problem is elsewhere in how you set up your server or set up the routes in code you're not showing us and you will need to show more code.

Comment: Do you define any route before? or it's only / ? Because if you've /, /users should work, otherwise, if you have define /service, i should be like /service/users.